# Mouse click and mouse over effect for turn.js not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, turnjs

I was working upon a website with a `flipbook` kind of jQuery effect provided by [turn.js](https://github.com/blasten/turn.js).

It was working very well on my development environment. Suddenly have found out that the `mouseover` effect and `mouseclick` has stopped working on browser `Chrome V29.0.1547.66m.`

It works perfectly with `V26.0.1410.63` and on other browsers (Firefox).
Need to know the reason and some workaround solution for the same.

[**Here is the link to my webpage**](http://www.rajametalgroup.com/products.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had checked your link, I think there is some problem in turn.min.js script. Use turn.js script in place of turn.min.js it is working fine on your link.

Answer (score 4):

As per issue no 399 posted on blasten/github https://github.com/blasten/turn.js/issues/399 change your turn.min.js to latest version of turn.js. This will surely solve your issue with chrome browsers' latest version on windows.

Answer (score 0):

hello
i was using the unminified version of turnjs and still had problems with some browsers, i read the code and discovered that mouse move events were not dispatched

i tested with 2 computers :

old Toshiba laptop with 1st-gen i7, Windows 7 Pro SP1, Opera 35.0.2066.68, Firefox 44.0.2 64Bits

brand new Intel NUC5i7RYH, Windows 8.1 Pro, same browser versions

mouse events
working properly on NUC + Firefox and Toshiba + Opera
NOT working on NUC + Opera and Toshiba + Firefox
uh ?

mouse || touch callbacks are set at line 28
touch capacity is detected at line 26

the isTouch test at line 26 returns true on some desktop browsers, which causes the mouse controls not to work

i noticed many tests provided on forum an blog posts didn't detect touch capacity properly, because they often check if touch APIs exist, which seems to be true in some Opera and Firefox browsers (i read some posts about people having the same problem with Chrome, mine works well)

i ended up using this test, which is far from perfect but does the job for now :

```
!(window.screenX != 0) && ('ontouchstart' in window || 'onmsgesturechange' in window);
```

i have no more problems, but this solution should be tested on many devices and the isTouch test must be improved

also, i got a bug in the zoom (line 90) while using latest version of jQuery, which i fixed by unchaining the two listeners as follows :

```
this.mousedown(zoomMethods._mousedown); // what ? chaining bug ?

this.click(zoomMethods._tap);
```